# What is Call Forwarding and Static Calls in PHP or otherwise Late static binding?

Tags: php, function, oop, static, late-static-binding

One code sample I have got from a website, but it was difficult for me to understand the output. I am sharing the code :

```
class A 
{
  public static function foo() 
  {
    static::who();
  }

  public static function who() 
  {
    echo __CLASS__."\n";
  }
}

class B extends A 
{
   public static function test() 
   {
      A::foo();
      parent::foo();
      self::foo();
   }

   public static function who() 
   {
     echo __CLASS__."\n";
   }
 }

class C extends B 
{
   public static function who() 
   {
      echo __CLASS__."\n";
   }
}

C::test();
```

The Output is as follows ::

```
A
C
C
```

I would be highly helped if the above output is explained. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What problem do you have in particular with understanding the output? Would you expect a different result? Do you not know where to start at all? Please be more specific, it's unclear whether we have to explain everything from classes to inheritance or just static calls.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> One code sample I have got from a website, but it was difficult for me
> to understand the output. I am sharing the code

This code is an exact replica from the PHP Manual of the **Late Static Binding** concept..

#### Explanation of this code from the manual..

> Late static bindings' resolution will stop at a fully resolved static
> call with no fallback. On the other hand, static calls using keywords
> like parent:: or self:: will forward the calling information.

[*Source*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)

### So let me explain in depth...

When you do .. `C::test();` , The `test()` under the `class B` will be called as there is no `test()` available on `class C`.

So you are obviously here..

```
   public static function test() 
   {
      A::foo();
      parent::foo();
      self::foo();
   }
```

#### Case 1 : `A::foo();`

As you read this from the above statement.. *Late static bindings' resolution will stop at a fully resolved static call with no fallback* , so since it is a fully resolved static call , you will get an output of `A`

#### Case 2 & 3 : `parent::foo();` and  `self::foo();`

Again, from the above statement.. *static calls using keywords like parent:: or self:: will forward the calling information.*

So this will obviously print C and C .. because since you did `C::test();` , The `class C` is the actual caller.

Comment: Dear Shankar, Thanks for your explanation. I had no idea about 'call forwarding'.

Comment: @user3401141, Your welcome. Is it clear now or its still unclear ? Feel free to ask.